# Proguard causing NoSuchMethodException

Tags: android, proguard

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("co.uk.MyApp.dir.TargetClass");
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", Report_Holder.class);
```

Throws a 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.main[class co.uk.MyApp.classes.Report_Holder]' error once I've prepared the app for release using Proguard.

I spent hours thinking the problem was in 'co.uk.MyApp.dir.TargetClass', commenting out things, re-releasing the app, and re-testing. But it turns out that the error is right at the root, at:

```
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", Report_Holder.class);
```

I then updated proguard-project.txt to include:

```
-dontobfuscate
-keeppackagenames
```

(I am using the Lint suggested method which suggested putting code into project.properties and putting the config in a text file), such as:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

But adding those 2 lines didn't have any effect.

So now I am wondering if;

a) I should add anything on top of '-keeppackagenames' etc.

b) Is proguard.config set up correctly; should ${sdk.dir} actually be a proper uri to the sdk

The class that it is targeting is like this:

```
public static void main(Report_Holder args) {
....
}
```

**Edit**

Or is it because I have 2 instances of this type of thing, both called 'main' ? But called in different activities.

```
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", Report_Holder.class);
Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", OtherReport_Holder.class);
```

And both targets being like this:

```
public static void main(Report_Holder args) {
....
}

public static void main(OtherReport_Holder args) {
....
}
```

Comment: main should ever be main(String[] args)

Comment: could you expand on that, Alex? Thanks

Comment: the name main for a method is the standard entry point, using the name main for other methods signatures, worsk, but is missleading. so better choose another name.

Comment: So I should change it to something like 'Method main = c.getDeclaredMethod("blah", Report_Holder.class);' and 'public static void blah(Report_Holder args) {' ?

Comment: yes, at least for design purpose and to not confuse yourself. this will not yet solve your problem but is a first step. then you must exclude youmr blah method from obfsucation. (look at proguad homepage examples). for analyze you print out the obfuscation.map Map file, and look what proguard has obfuscated and what not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know how to use proguard, you should add the option `-keepattributes Signature`
. this is necesary when using generics (collections).

For all methods beeing called via reflection, you must explictly exclude them from obfsucation. use the option to output the obfuscation map file, to see if your rules had the desired effect.

Comment: I can't see any reference to -keepsignatures in proguard. However, I've updated my 'main' names as you suggested, and have looked into proguard a bit more. As you said, it didn't fix my problem. I have posted a followup at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703291/proguard-causing-nosuchmethodexception-followup